# Read from file and create associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, text-files, associative-array

I am able to read from a file and create an array however I get the following error: Notice: Undefined offset: 1. Within my array there is one element that is empty and I don't understand why it is empty.

My text file is in the following format:

```
#EXTINF:0,ABC family USA[]http://localhost/IpInfo/index.html  
#EXTINF:0,CBC[]http://localhost/IpInfo/index1.html
#EXTINF:0,A&E[]http://localhost/IpInfo/index2.html
```

Here is my code:

```
$fh = fopen('file1.txt', 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize('file1.txt'));
$arr = array();
$my_array = explode("\r\n", $theData);

foreach($my_array as $line){
    $tmp = explode("[]", $line);
    $arr[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}
fclose($fh);

echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($arr);
```

I'm not quite sure what the problem is? Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your input data doesn't use `\r\n` as the line delimiter? I'm not sure whether I got the problem completely. Also you might want to take empty lines into account.

I would use the `file()` function, which simplifies to iterate over the lines of a file and can handle Windows and Unix line feeds and check for empty lines:

```
$arr = array();

foreach(file('a.txt') as $line){
    // I'm using `trim()` here since $line
    // will still contain the newline delimiter
    $line = trim($line);

    // Skip empty lines
    if(empty($line) {
        continue;
    }

    $tmp = explode("[]", $line);
    $arr[$tmp[0]] = trim($tmp[1]);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

**Output:**

```
<pre>Array
(
    [#EXTINF:0,ABC family USA] => http://localhost/IpInfo/index.html
    [#EXTINF:0,CBC] => http://localhost/IpInfo/index1.html
    [#EXTINF:0,A&E] => http://localhost/IpInfo/index2.html
)
```

Comment: thank you however I still get an error at: $arr[$tmp[0]] = trim($tmp[1]); Same error as before, undefined offset 1 ?

Comment: @dantheman What if we use `if(!empty($line) ...` and put the assignment inside if?

Comment: @user4035 Possible  too. I like to revert the logic to keep less indention and to get cleaner code. However in this case it would be ok to put it into the `if(!empty($line)) { ... ` block

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the explode function splits your read-in data at the "\r\n". And you have a new line after the last line, and that's what results in the last "array" with no keys or values. To fix this, replace this line : `$my_array = explode("\r\n", $theData);` with these:

```
$my_array = explode("\r\n", $theData);
array_pop($my_array);
```

Comment: plus one, since the hint: "you have an empty line at the end", was posted by you first!